# While True python statement to execute code biweekly on a specific date WITHOUT cron?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

How can I execute code, like a simple print("whatever"), biweekly, at a specific time. For example, every other Monday print("test") at 1 PM EST. This has to be without cron. I realize there are numerous solutions using crontab. Not an option for me. The other closest solutions on here relies on the calendar library, and executes code weekly on a specific day, but not biweekly.

Does anybody know of a simple and easy way to do this?

i've tried this
[Python scheduling a job starting every weekday and running every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086739/python-scheduling-a-job-starting-every-weekday-and-running-every-hour)

I was expecting a way to run tasks biweekly, but its not possible with that library.

edit:

basically this, but biweekly only:

```
# Schedule Library imported
import schedule
import time

# Functions setup
def sudo_placement():
    print("Do something ")

schedule.every().monday.at("09:01").do(sudo_placement)
schedule.every().monday.at("09:02").do(sudo_placement)
schedule.every().monday.at("09:03").do(sudo_placement)


while True:

    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Schedule a job for the first monday you want it to run and have that job once it's done the needful schedule itself for 2 weeks later...?

Comment: sort of. so, a while True loop that checks datetime every minute... if it is equal to Monday at 1 PM, print("whatever"). then, continue running loop, and if it is equal to the next next Monday, execute the same print("whatever").

Comment: kind of like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-schedule-library/ schedule.every().monday.do(good_luck)
 but only every OTHER monday

Comment: more like this: schedule.every().monday.at("13:00").do(sudo_placement)

Comment: Note that cron itself is out-of-date; the modern alternative is systemd timer units.

Comment: "Every other Monday": with what origin? Usually, one would say "every 1st and 3rd Monday of the month", or something that specifies which of the Mondays we are talking about. Another possibility would be "every other Monday, starting with the first Monday in January".

Comment: (To be a little more explicit about what I was alluding to with my earlier comment: There are a lot of answers that are "without cron" but aren't native Python; if what you want is not just without-cron but in-native-Python, you should probably say that explicitly).

Comment: Anyhow -- if you want something more powerful than the `schedule` library that's still native-Python, consider https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler. (Not adding an answer because library recommendation requests are off-topic, so if that _is_ a valid answer then the question shouldn't be allowed here in the first place).

Comment: When you say "without cron", do you mean the cron program _specifically_?  Or do you mean _any_ external task scheduler system?

Comment: gents, i mean native python. I'd like to run this while True loop on a windows server to eventually send out email reminders every other week on Monday at 1300 hours

Comment: would it be valid and a lot easier to just run a while True loop  wait 336 hours, run job, repeat? I have no idea how to get apscheduler running. I'm surprised there's no better library for this. :|

Comment: `time.sleep()` isn't guaranteed to be exact, so no, it's not something you can rely on for scheduling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use sometimes [`croniter`](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/). Not quite for the need you have, but more to limit the rate of certain updates on some client code, by specifying a "schedule" using cron expressions.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```py
from croniter import croniter
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

def every_other(it):
    while True:
        t = it.get_next(datetime)
        yield t
        it.get_next(datetime)

# for the example
DO_SLEEP = False  
max_runs = 5

# every other Monday 1pm ET, starting with the first Monday in January 2023
base = datetime(2023, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST5EDT'))
it = croniter('0 13 * * Mon', base)

for t in every_other(it):
    sleep_time = t.timestamp() - time.time()
    if sleep_time < 0:
        continue
    if max_runs <= 0:
        break
    max_runs -= 1
    print(f'next run: {t:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z}')
    if DO_SLEEP:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
    # do whatever
```

This prints out (running on 2023-02-12):

```
next run: 2023-02-13 13:00:00 EST
next run: 2023-02-27 13:00:00 EST
next run: 2023-03-13 13:00:00 EDT
next run: 2023-03-27 13:00:00 EDT
next run: 2023-04-10 13:00:00 EDT
```

#### Shift the biweekly sequence

Say we wanted the biweekly series to start on `2023-02-20` instead of `2023-02-13`. Simply change the `base` above. For example:

```py
base = datetime(2023, 2, 20, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('EST5EDT'))
```

The run dates will then be:

```
next run: 2023-02-20 13:00:00 EST
next run: 2023-03-06 13:00:00 EST
next run: 2023-03-20 13:00:00 EDT
next run: 2023-04-03 13:00:00 EDT
next run: 2023-04-17 13:00:00 EDT
```

In other words, just set `base` to whichever first Monday you'd like in the series, before 1pm ET (or any datetime between the previous Monday after 1pm to the chosen start day, before 1pm).

#### Notes

1. To actually run on the prescribed schedule (every other Monday at 1pm ET), then set `DO_SLEEP = True`.
2. To run "forever", remove the `max_runs` logic, which is there only for this example.
3. That program can be forcefully interrupted (e.g. reboot, or `kill -9`) and restarted at any time: it will resume with waiting for the next "other Monday" in the series (anchored on the first Monday in 2023).
4. This could be extended to handle multiple schedules and actions, but would need a stack of "next run times". Relatively easy to do, but beyond the scope of this narrow question.
5. For very long wait times (two weeks), I don't know if a single `time.sleep()` is accurate enough. It might be worth implementing a `wait_until(timestamp)` that waits shorter and shorter periods until the prescribed time. This could then be made quite accurate (well under a second).

Comment: this just seems to print out the dates i'm interested in, but it's not a while True loop waiting for those dates to occur, to eventually trigger a job when the date time is met.

Comment: If you change `DO_SLEEP=True`, then it will wait until the next date.

Comment: I think this works... it executes when I initially run which isn't a huge problem. I'll test this more. thank you so much

Comment: It shouldn't execute initially. If you have `DO_SLEEP = True`, then the first thing it will do is literally sleep until the first "other-monday" iterator that is later than the time now (at the start of the program). Also: beware to remove the whole `max_runs` thing, if you want this to run forever.

Comment: Added a few notes, FYI. How robust and accurate do you need this to be? Is your plan to have only one schedule and action?

Comment: basically just need it to go off every 2nd Monday at 1300. it's triggering a twilio call to send text messages to multiple users, reminding them to do something. do you know how to shift the next run to execute next week, rather than two weeks from now? still would like to continue biweekly execution. so, next week, 2/20, then 3/6, etc.

Comment: Sure, see updated answer, section "Shift the biweekly sequence".